# Курносый нос

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вот думаю: а правильно ли говорить "курносый нос"? Получается, что это нос, у которого тоже есть нос, который вздернутый.)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из словаря:

КУРНОСЫЙ,  Разг. 1. Короткий и вздёрнутый (о носе).2. О человеке с коротким и вздёрнутым носом. Курносое лицо. Курносая девчонка.

Это метонимия - перенос названия свойства, качества на то или того, что или кто обнаруживает, имеет это свойство, качество. Получается: курносый человек (человек с коротким носом)  - курносое лицо - курносый нос.

Курносый  (изначально "корноносый") - это "корный" (короткий) нос.  Этот же корень имеют слова корнать, кромсать, а также куртка, кора.